# Different return type based on parameter type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I want to have an interface where I know the parameter is going to be 1 of a few different types (coming from a 3rd party library) and based on what type it is, the return type will change, with some types also being from a 3rd party library, or being a basic type like void or null.

Here is the simplest code to replicate my issue

```
type foo = {
  statusCode: number;
  body: string;
}
type fooReturn = string; // in reality, this could be a complex type

type bar = {
  results: [];
}
type barReturn = number; // in reality, this could be a complex type

interface foobar {
  myFunc<T extends (foo | bar)>(event: T): T extends foo ? fooReturn : barReturn;
}

class myClass implements foobar {
  // the below code errors
  myFunc(event: foo) { // we tell TS that the param is of type foo
    return 'hello' // so the return must be a string
  }
}
```

The error is

```
Property 'myFunc' in type 'myClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'foobar'.
  Type '(event: foo) => string' is not assignable to type '(event: T) => T extends foo ? string : number'.
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'foo'.
        Type 'foo | bar' is not assignable to type 'foo'.
          Type 'bar' is missing the following properties from type 'foo': statusCode, body
```

Comment: Did you tried using type-guard and explicitly typecasting it? Something like ***[this](https://tsplay.dev/w2g4bN)***

Comment: TS compiler is not complaing about return type - it is complaining about `foobar` interface not implemented correctly. In `foobar` you say that the event can be a `bar`, but your `myClass` excludes such possibility

Comment: I don't want to have to write out the whole of `myFunc` again like that, I would like to have it so I can just pass the type of `event` and it then figures out what the return should be for type hinting. Is that possible? I appreciate I may not be using the correct things at all to try and do this

Comment: It seems like you don't want the `myFunc` to be generic but rather the entire interface, so that `myClass` implements only `foobar<foo>` and not something else.

Comment: @Bergi I do want it to be generic, so I get the typings of what event is, and what I should return from `myClass` but I appreciate I might have got this totally wrong in the first place, and interfaces might not be the answer at all

Comment: @MrPablo if you implement an interface with a generic method, that means you must implement a *generic method*, supporting all of the declared event types. You cannot implement it for only `foo` events. So what do you want `myClass.myFunc` to actually do?

Comment: ① Please [edit] the code to adhere to conventional naming patterns, so as not to distract from your question.  Type names and class names are conventionally written in UpperPascalCase, not lowerPascalCase. ② You do not want `myFunc` to be generic. Possibly you want `Foobar` itself to be generic, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOKJRw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like i was missing the generic parameter on Foobar. Now my next task is to support more than two function param types and return types

Comment: That sounds like a followup question and it's therefore out of scope here.  Shall I write up my suggestion above as an answer post? May I edit your question to make the names conventional while I'm at it?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please feel free

Comment: Okay, I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be that you've incorrectly *scoped* the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter for your intent.  The type

```
interface Foobar {
    myFunc<T extends Foo | Bar>(event: T): T extends Foo ? FooReturn : BarReturn;
}
```

is a specific type with a generic method. Generic methods have the generic type parameter scoped to the call signature, meaning the *caller* decides what type argument goes in there.  If I want to implement a `Foobar`, then its `myFunc()` method has to allow the caller to call with whatever `T` they want.  It must support *both* `myFunc(event: Foo): FooReturn` *and* `myFunc(event: Bar): BarReturn`.  But `MyClass` does not implement that correctly; it only supports `Foo` and not `Bar`.

Instead, you probably want

```
interface Foobar<T extends Foo | Bar> {
    myFunc(event: T): T extends Foo ? FooReturn : BarReturn;
}
```

which is a *generic* type, with a *specific* method.  Generic types have the generic type parameter scoped to the type itself, meaning that the *implementer* decides what type argument goes in there.  With that definition, you need to decide whether you're implementing `Foobar<Foo>` or `Foobar<Bar>`.  Once you make that decision, the type argument for `T` is chosen and fixed. The call signature for `myFunc()` isn't generic.  And your `MyClass` does properly implement `Foobar<Foo>`:

```
class MyClass implements Foobar<Foo> {
    myFunc(event: Foo) { // okay
        return 'hello'
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUDOwCGwArjgMJwAmEAXFAHZEC2ARhAE4Dcm2zlIteNgEs6Acy4BfdKEiwEAJQjE2dZLmDCxHKAHodUEVDYR8AGyGgANFGAALITigBjOEVMUorKPmdxGYUwgADxtwCHRpMKgAIXw2NQxsIwgcN2AcWgBtAF1JSNlYtkVlVRQGFnZtPQNVYzMLEGs7B183Dy8fF39AkJlw9BFgdgAzfCdoeDhmOIAeABUoYKG6CkdJqAAfGLiAPjRuLEYQGCI6JwAKCAA3CDpgWjmASgfFoOXVuUQAfk-iohUoLRCn8VHl0E5TPgcI4ALIgUiQ6EGboQRi3dKfaZsGaTPaJbBHE5nS43O60SaPfZJJLGEpQADktggplMcHpBygUgkQA)

Answer (score 0):

I think the *correct* way to handle this is by using [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Then you can use a type guard to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the `event` parameter and return the correct type.

```
type Foo = {
  statusCode: number;
  body: string;
};
type FooReturn = string;

type Bar = {
  results: [];
};
type BarReturn = number;

interface FooBar {
  myFunc(event: Foo): FooReturn;
  myFunc(event: Bar): BarReturn;
  myFunc(event: Foo | Bar): FooReturn | BarReturn;
}

class myClass implements FooBar {
  myFunc(event: Foo): FooReturn;
  myFunc(event: Bar): BarReturn;
  myFunc(event: Foo | Bar): FooReturn | BarReturn{
    if ("results" in event) {
      return 666;
    } else {
      return "hello";
    }
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBnYBDYAV2wGE4ATCALigDtCBbAIwgCcBuTKJikG3VgEtaAc04BfTqEiwEAJQhFWtZDmBDRndNOgAhPK1UYsrCNkIAbYNhoBtALoSp4PQYVKVKeszZbhwNgAzPABjaHg4fUNjKAYQGEJaEIAKCAA3CFpgGgiAShz5RUJlTiw4hKTUjKyaKPyoKPdi2lLY+MSU9Mzs2UQAHwaDeoim5SgBxqKS9HF0dBCLPGxsNpJF5ahBBjALCAZulYiotC5yjqrugrhhwo9Ws8qumsHWesm70-bH6p6I8ZebnBRioJm4prQYlhBIEoMkAESmcxWbBwzYqJ7AXInLA4qCmDxQABsxNaWHEUAgFmw0EhOPxzSgcIAFpSLHA4aSoLMyTN0EA)

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I don't want to have to overload `myFunc` in the class `myClass`, as I know when `myFunc` is called, it will be either `foo` or `bar`. I just want typings to help me say what the return should be when `event` is `foo` for example. `myFunc` won't be called from anywhere else (it will be fired once by AWS Lambda, passing in the event data